# Find printer from my wifi using iphone sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, printing, wifi

Can anyone please help me how can i list the printers connected to my wifi in my **iphone sdk**, and also i want to print my pdf using the selected printer. Please help me. Using Bonjour i got the printers list, but no printer status. Please help me

Comment: Check [bonjour service](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NetServices/Introduction.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help, But my situation is i initiate printing from server and i have to watch the printing status from my iphone device, Using IP and port number. Can anyone please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the [UIPrintInteractionController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPrintInteractionController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class. It shows an alert/popover where you can choose one of the printer that are AirPrint enabled (obviously that are on the same LAN).
Take a look at [this sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PrintWebView/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010311) provided by Apple, it shows how to print the content of a `UIWebView` but it's simple to adapt it to print documents or images.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the example itself to print a pdf in apple documentation:

```
- (IBAction)printContent:(id)sender {
    UIPrintInteractionController *pic = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
    if  (pic && [UIPrintInteractionController canPrintData: self.myPDFData] ) {
        pic.delegate = self;

        UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
        printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGeneral;
        printInfo.jobName = [self.path lastPathComponent];
        printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexLongEdge;
        pic.printInfo = printInfo;
        pic.showsPageRange = YES;
        pic.printingItem = self.myPDFData;

        void (^completionHandler)(UIPrintInteractionController *, BOOL, NSError *) =
           ^(UIPrintInteractionController *pic, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {
             self.content = nil;
             if (!completed && error)
                  NSLog(@"FAILED! due to error in domain %@ with error code %u",
                  error.domain, error.code);
        };
        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        [pic presentFromBarButtonItem:self.printButton animated:YES
            completionHandler:completionHandler];
        } else {
        [pic presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you.